# How to pass SortField,SortOrder,Filters of load method through normal method from DataModel class?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

In case of Lazy loading I override load method with arguments (int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map filters),
here I put custom filter in filters by which I can filter criteria in `Dao` class.

But when I wat to implement live scrolling with custom filtering in `Dao` class then how I shall pass load method's arguments(String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map filters) from DataModel class. it is necessary
because I want to sort and filter some columns with criteria in `Dao` class. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement your own lazy model like this:

```
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel

public class MyBeanClass{
    LazyDataModel lazyModel

    public MyBeanClass(){
        lazyModel = new LazyDataModel() {
            @Override
            List load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, boolean sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
                // here fetch data from your DAO and return as a list
            }
        }
    }    
  }
```

and then use it with your table

```
<p:dataTable ... value="#{myBean.lazyModel}" ... >
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but I don't want to implement this in LazyDataModel because with live Scrolling it is incompatible. As I want live scrolling with custom filter features in dao class. Is it necessery to pass sortOrder,SortField,filters arguments to dao??

Comment: I guess it is not strictly necessary, but would probably yield better performance.

Comment: And according to the showcase lazy models should work with live scrolling: `In order to enable lazy loading, a LazyDataModel needs to be implemented to query the datasource when pagination, sorting, filtering or live scrolling happens.`